# git tf configure command error (git-tf nothing to configure)

Tags: git, tfs, git-tf

After creating a git repository (repo1) using GIT Bash by pulling a project from TFS2012 server 'A', I am trying to configure a project on another TFS2012 server 'B' using below command from **repo1** directory as explained [here](http://gittf.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Configure&referringTitle=Home):

```
git tf configure http://localmachine:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection $/PersonalSite/repo1
```

But below error is displaying:

**ERROR:**

```
git-tf: nothing to configure. please specify an option to configure
```

I have tried googling this error, but can't find much help.

Note: Ultimately I need to checkin to TFS2012 server 'B' for changes to persist.

Can you please help with resolving this error?
Thanks

Comment: Are you really using backticks?  Are you on Windows or Unix?  If Windows:  from a Windows command-prompt?  Git Bash?  PowerShell?

Comment: @EdwardThomson I am using Windows 7 and running this command through Git Bash command shell.

Comment: @EdwardThomson I am not using backticks in the url, its just stackoverflow's requirement to enclose local string containing urls to be wrapped up in single quotes.

Comment: Is that `DefaultCollection*s*` or `DefaultCollection`?  Did you mistype the name of the collection?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Sorry! it was DefaultCollection, and that is what I am using in command, just mistyped in question above, but still no joy. Same error.

Answer (score 7):

You will get this error if you already have configured a tfs repo. To see if you already have it configured do this..

```
git-tf configure -l
```

If you need to change it to another tfs repo use the --force switch.

Comment: Josh, there isn't any repo configured yet, however, when I view the list, get below output.

$ git-tf configure -l
Server URI : http://localhost:8080/tfs/DefaultCollections
TFS Server Path : $/WTMain
Default Depth : Shallow
Tag Changeset Commits : true
Include Meta Data in Changeset Comments : false
....
Repo doesn't exist, so still a question, why it is failing :(. Thanks for your answer.